# collapsing bootstrap column horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 column on a row, and I want to collapse the left one horizontally(to the left), leaving the right one on the left side (this one also have animation moving to left). I'm currently using Bootstrap 4.1 and JQuery 3.4.1. (I'm sorry this can't run in code snippet because I don't know how to insert bootsrap)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#col1").collapse({
    toggle : true
  })

});
```

```html
<!--Body-->
<div class="row h-50">
  <div style="background-color : red;" id="col1" class="col-6 collapse">
    <div class="h-100">contents to hide</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2" class="col-6">
    <div style="background-color : gray" class="h-100">some other contents</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1" class="button" id="somebutton">somebutton</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this snippet will do the trick for you. See full-page snippet for details

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#col1").collapse({
    toggle : true
  })

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Body-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1" class="button" id="somebutton">somebutton</button>
```

Comment: my code is exactly like that. and I want to animate the flex-size change. maybe something like this.
http://jsfiddle.net/2gbPg/2/

Comment: ok, its that you are looking for a vertical collapse animation, which jquery can't do, apply CSS for that